# Access Values of Dynamically Created EditTexts

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Based on the value entered into an edittext I am performing a select on a sqlite table and will need to display results from that query as

Textview     EditText    Button

When the button is clicked, I need to access the text value of the EditText directly to it's left.

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.tl);
var connection = inst.conn();
connection.Open();
var c = connection.CreateCommand();
c.CommandText = "Select * From OnOrder Where ItemNumber = '" + contents + "'";
SqliteDataReader dr = c.ExecuteReader();

                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    TextView tv;
                    EditText et;
                    Button bt;
                    TableRow tr;
                    var tlp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(2);
                    var tlp2 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(3);

                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        tr = new TableRow(this);

                        partdesc.Text = dr[2].ToString();
                        tv = new TextView(this);
                        tv.Text = dr[0].ToString() + "   " + dr[3].ToString() + "   ";
                        tr.AddView(tv);

                        et = new EditText(this);
                        et.Hint = "Quantity";
                        et.LayoutParameters = tlp;
                        tr.AddView(et);

                        bt = new Button(this);
                        bt.LayoutParameters = tlp2;
                        bt.Text = "Receive";
                        bt.Click += delegate
                        {
                          //Don't know what to do here to make it so that when this button is clicked it acts on the values of the edittext just created to its left
                        };
                        tr.AddView(bt);

                        tl.AddView(tr);
                    }
                }

                dr.Close();
                connection.Close();

            }
```

Edit:  Code that works

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.tl);
var connection = inst.conn();
connection.Open();
var c = connection.CreateCommand();
c.CommandText = "Select * From OnOrder Where ItemNumber = '" + contents + "'";
SqliteDataReader dr = c.ExecuteReader();

                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    TextView tv;
                    EditText et;
                    Button bt;
                    TableRow tr;
                    var tlp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(2);
                    var tlp2 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(3);
                    var cnt = 0;

                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        tr = new TableRow(this);
                        var record = cnt.ToString();
                        partdesc.Text = dr[2].ToString();
                        tv = new TextView(this);
                        tv.Text = dr[0].ToString() + "   " + dr[3].ToString() + "   ";
                        tr.AddView(tv);

                        et = new EditText(this);
                        et.Hint = "Quantity";
                        et.InputType = (int)Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassNumber;
                        et.LayoutParameters = tlp;
                        tr.AddView(et);

                        bt = new Button(this);
                        bt.LayoutParameters = tlp2;
                        bt.Text = "Receive";
                        bt.Click += delegate
                        {
                            getValue(Convert.ToInt32(record));

                        };
                        tr.AddView(bt);

                        tl.AddView(tr);
                        cnt++;
                    }
                }

                dr.Close();
                connection.Close();

            }
        }
    }

    public void getValue(int index)
    {
        TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.tl);
        TableRow tr = (TableRow)tl.GetChildAt(index);
        EditText et = (EditText)tr.GetChildAt(1);
        var inst = new Inventory.invChange();
        Dialog d = inst.showBuilder(this, "Test", et.Text);
        d.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the code I got to work.  Using the delegate the way that was suggested returns a blank value.

Answer (score 1):

`Console.WriteLine (et.Text);`

Comment: et.Text hasn't been set yet.  The user will be entering a value into et and then clicking bt and I need to be able to reference whatever instance of et is next to the clicked instance of bt.

Comment: The delegate isn't run until the button is clicked.

Comment: Ok.  Then how do I do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: As Jon said, you can just access the "et" variable in your delegate to get access to that field.

Answer (score 0):

You could always set the `tag` of the `EditText` to something relevant.

For instance, you could number them. If you click on #4, to get the one to the left/right, whatever, do 4-1=3, and then retrieve the `EditText` with tag=3.